# Set Images one by one

Tags: android, image, imageview, android-imageview

I'm new in developing so I want to ask this question, sorry if it's stupid

I have 6 different `ImageView`s and 6 images, how can I set images into `ImageView`s so that they appear on click one by one with some delay, like 1 second? Now they appear all together at the same time

```
private int[] images;
private int[] containers;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    images = new int[] {R.drawable.wale,
                        R.drawable.btrfly,
                        R.drawable.cat,
                        R.drawable.dog,
                        R.drawable.fish,
                        R.drawable.dolphin};
    containers = new int[] {R.id.container1,
                            R.id.container2,
                            R.id.container3,
                            R.id.container4,
                            R.id.container5,
                            R.id.container6};

    for (int i = 0; i<containers.length; i++) {
        final ImageView temp = findViewById(containers[i]);
        temp.setImageResource(R.drawable.placeholder);

    }

    Button load = findViewById(R.id.btnLoad);
    load.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            for ( int i =0; i<containers.length; i++) {
                final ImageView temp = findViewById(containers[i]);
                temp.setImageResource(images[i]);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow (I noticed it's your first day here). Please show some code so that we may better understand your situation (I already have some general idea but I want to make sure I'm correct instead of guessing)

Comment: The beginning of the method seems to be missing - is it onCreate()?

Comment: Yes, it's onCreate

Comment: I edited the missing part in. Please correct it if anything is wrong

Comment: thank you again! I've edited a little part and now it works fine! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `postDelayed()` of [android.os.Handler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler#postdelayed) like this:

```
final int baseDelay = 1000;
final Handler handler = new Handler();

load.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            for (int i = 0; i < containers.length; i++) {
                    final int ifinal = i;
                    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
                    public void run(){
                    final ImageView temp = findViewById(containers[ifinal]);                       
                    temp.setImageResource(images[ifinal]);
                    }
                }, i * baseDelay);

            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you so much for help! I'll try it!

Comment: @YuryPilath - that's what happens if I write code without an IDE: thanks for the edit :)